# downloading image into NSHomeDirectory by using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

```
__block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
__weak UIImageView *weakImageView = self.headpic;
[self.headpic setImageWithURL:imageUrl placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize){
if (!activityIndicator) {
    [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]];
    activityIndicator.center = weakImageView.center;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  }
}
                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){
                      [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                      activityIndicator = nil;
                  }];
```

this code can set headpic's image, and I want to download the server image(from imageUrl) to `NSHomeDirectory` at the same time, how to do?

Comment: So are you asking how to save an `UIImage` to file?

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for your reply, i think i get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Look at EGOCache for store images locally.
https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache
You can use default EGOCache directory (inside NSCachesDirectory) or initialize it with your own directory.

Usage is very simple:

```
[[EGOCache globalCache] setImage:image forKey:@"your_key"];
```